# Unable to create simple Inventory Adjustment: invalid field for customer?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Why, when I attempt to create an Inventory Adjustment I get the error:

> You have entered an Invalid Field Value 12112 for the following field: customer

I can confirm that that customer entity id is valid and that they are part of the correct subsidiary.

Any ideas what the heck is going wrong and how I can create a simple Inventory Adjustment?

```
require(['N/ui/serverWidget', 
        'N/email', 
        'N/runtime', 
        'N/search',
        'N/file',
        'N/config',
        'N/format',
        'N/record',
        'N/log',
        'N/runtime'],

function(ui, email, runtime, search, file, config, format, record, log, runtime) {

    // Attempt to create an IA

    var ia = record.create({
        type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT, 
        isDynamic: true
    });

    // Set IA fields
    var values = {
        // 'entity': '12112',  // Dummy customer
        'customer': '12112',  
        'subsidiary': '2',
        'account': '307',
        'class': '36',
        //'adjlocation': '2'
    };

    for (var key in values) {
        ia.setValue({
            fieldId: key,
            value: values[key]
        });
    }

    // Set IA Inventory sublist fields/lines
    var line1 = {
        'item': '61',
        'location': '1',
        'adjustqtyby': '-1',
        'department': '3',
        'class': '36',
    };

    ia.selectNewLine({
        sublistId: 'inventory'
    });

    for (var field in line1) {
        ia.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'inventory',
            fieldId: field,
            value: line1[field]
        });
    }

    ia.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'inventory'
    });

    var recordId = ia.save({
        enableSourcing: false,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: false
    });

    var x = 0;  // Add breakpoint for NS Debugger

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the record in "dynamic" mode, so you need to set fields in the same order as you would in the UI. In particular, you need to select a `subsidiary` before you can set the `customer` field.

Swapping these order of these two lines will most probably solve your error.

```
var values = {
    // 'entity': '12112',  // Dummy customer
    'subsidiary': '2',
    'customer': '12112',
    'account': '307',
    'class': '36',
    //'adjlocation': '2'
};
```

However, take note that `for..in` [does not guarantee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) that it will follow any particular order, so theoretically NetSuite could push an update to their JavaScript engine at any time that would order things differently and break your code.